# CSS class not defined in theme.scss in shopify store

Tags: css, class, shopify, liquid

I am working on a shopify store and I want to change the properties of a class. Please see the code below:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon-facebook" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path fill="#444" d="M18.56 31.36V17.28h4.48l.64-5.12h-5.12v-3.2c0-1.28.64-2.56 2.56-2.56h2.56V1.28H19.2c-3.84 0-7.04 2.56-7.04 7.04v3.84H7.68v5.12h4.48v14.08h6.4z"/></svg>
```

I would like to modify the properties of the "icon-facebook" class. Normally, this class would be defined in the theme.scss.liquid file (which I though is where all the classes are defined, I have been able to change properties of other classes in that file) however, the "icon-facebook" class is not there. Is there another file where the class could be defined? I have looked everywhere but have not found it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just style it in your main project file.because styling in the project file also adds the styles as from the external files.
And then you will have all the styles added to your class `icon-facebook` from both the files.